# Is it possible to get the SQL that would be generated, without running the mapping?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We can see the SQL's generated by PowerCenter in the session log file once a mapping has been run. So to get these SQLs we have to run the mapping. I would like to know if there is any way to get the SQL that PowerCenter **would** generate without actually running the mapping, so that we can analyse it, fix it or apply relevant database indexes etc. in case of any issues.

If this is possible then please tell me how.

Comment: +1 great question, and a great answer - please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the **Source Qualifier**, go to **Properties** tab and edit the **SQL Query** property. There you can see the **Generate SQL** button that will create the SQL statement.
This also works for lookups where you can find the **Lookup Sql Override** property.
Please note that this will not include the source filter (for Lookup).

Comment: Hello @Maciejg, i need to connect you on xml analyzer. Could you pls reply back?

Comment: Sure. @KoushikRoy. Just let me know how to reach you.

Comment: pls mail me at gameroy007@gmail . I can send you my requirement. You can whats app me too.

Comment: i emailed you at Maciejg@gmail. Pls let me know if it reaches you and we can take it further

Answer (score 2):

Run the mapping in test mode. In test mode, no data is inserted/updated in target tables. But you will still get the SQL queries from session log.

To enable test mode, go to the properties tab of the session and check the "Enable Test Load" option. You can leave the "Number of rows to test" value to 1 (default).

Answer (score -1):

I think that is not possible in Informatica PowerCenter.

Comment: We can very well do it I believe as mentioned above by Maciejg. Did I figure out the question properly?

Comment: Well, yes, we can get SQL SELECT statements against the databases (SQ and LOOKUP), but not the INSERT statements without running the actual mappings. INSERT statements are also SQL statements...

Comment: If you want insert statements, you'd need to use Pushdown Optimization. There you can get full insert-select statements, in the preview. So this is also possible.

Comment: pls mail me at gameroy007@gmail . I can send you my requirement. You can whats app me too.